# Время соединения сокета

Tags: php, websocket

Поднял сайт с чатом. Проблема следующая, сервер передает данные как я бы хотел, но соединение обрывается через минуту. Это время по-умолчанию, его можно изменить?
Сервер на php, js соединяется с ним с помощью прокси (костыль, не нашел wss для php сразу)

Comment: А как вы сокет создаете? Большинство функций для создания соединения имеют параметр таймаута. Передайте отрицательное значение, скорее всего это решит проблему

Comment: Нашел default_socket_timeout  для php.ini, кажется это оно. Странно почему не нашел его раньше. Большое спасибо. 
Если нетрудно, можете подсказать, время соединения в 5 минут создаст сильную нагрузку на сайт? Обычные чат-комнаты, только текст

Comment: UPD: оказалось кроме настроек php все зависило от таймаутов haproxy, почему я сразу не додумался